# What does そこによるところは大きい mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

could anyone help me with a sentence? It was from an article in the Asahi about the leadership change in North Korea. The full sentence is 拉致被害者の早い救出も、そこによるところは大きい。I understand the first part of the sentence - the rapid rescue of the abduction victims as well. However, I am not sure about the second part. How do you translate そこによる and ところは大きい into English? Is による　似寄る or　に拠る? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `による` in the sentence seems to be `拠る/依る　-> depend on` or `因る/由る -> due to` But it needs more context to clarify the meaning. Can you quote the previous sentences?

Comment: Well, it goes like this:　腎愚の次第で民は泣き、国際社会は迷惑を被る。拉致被害者の早い救出も、そこによるところは大きい-世継ぎへの忠誠心争いや、どさくさの権力争いで、ミサイルや砲弾が他国へ飛ぶ事態もないとはいえない・

Comment: If you go further back, you got this sentence: そして早々と三代目の世襲が宣言された。だが、その資質のほどはほとんど知られていない。

Did you get what そこ refers to from this? Does it refer to the new North Korean leader's disposition / 資質?

Answer (score 4):

> 賢愚の次第で民は泣き、国際社会は迷惑を被る。拉致被害者の早い救出も、そこによるところは大きい

In this context, `そこ (that/it)` points to `賢愚 (to be wise or foolish) の次第` and `よる` should be `依る`, meaning `depends on`.

So it reads: the rapid rescue of the abduction victims also largely depends on it. (`it` refers to the degree of being wise or foolish.)

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thank you very much. It was a hard article.